# Form is not inserting entered data in the database, but doesn't show any errors

Tags: php, database, insert, submit

guys, I hope someone can help me find the problem in this code that is keeping it from inserting the entered data in the database.

I have seen similar threads around here, I corrected one or two things and still it doesn't seem to work, that's why I created this post.

Also, this code worked flawlessly when it had only three form fields/variables. Now that I have created a few more, it wont send any submitted values to the database.

If anyone should ask, the function that shows the result in the same page is working fine, since I have tried inserting values in the database manually and they show in the file, what leads me to think that the problem is really with the insert function.

Can anyone help me find why it's not going?

```
    <?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("activitytest1");
if(isset($_POST['type']))       { $type = $_POST['type']; }
if(isset($_POST['description'])){ $description = $_POST['description']; }
if(isset($_POST['author']))     { $author = $_POST['author']; }
if(isset($_POST['pre']))        { $pre = $_POST['pre']; }
if(isset($_POST['while']))      { $while = $_POST['while']; }
if(isset($_POST['postact']))    { $postact = $_POST['postact']; }
if(isset($_POST['outcome']))    { $outcome = $_POST['outcome']; }
if(isset($_POST['path']))       { $path = $_POST['path']; }
if(isset($_POST['books']))      { $books = $_POST['books']; }
if(isset($_POST['grouping']))   { $grouping = $_POST['grouping']; }
if(isset($_POST['time']))       { $time = $_POST['time']; }
if(isset($_POST['submit']))     { $submit = $_POST['submit']; }

$dbLink = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_query("SET character_set_client=utf8", $dbLink);
    mysql_query("SET character_set_connection=utf8", $dbLink);

if (!empty($_POST['submit']))
{
if($type&&$description&&$author&&$pre&&$while&&$postact&&$outcome&&$path&&$books&&$grouping&&$time) {
$insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO activitytest1 (type, description, author, pre, while, postact, outcome, path, books, grouping, time) VALUES ('".$_POST['type']."','".$_POST['description']."','".$_POST['author']."','".$_POST['pre']."', '".$_POST['while']."','".$_POST['postact']."','".$_POST['outcome']."','".$_POST['path']."', '".$_POST['books']."','".$_POST['grouping']."','".$_POST['time']."',)");
} else {
                    die ("Failed to connect to mysql: " . mysql_error());
}

}

$dbLink = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_query("SET character_set_results=utf8", $dbLink);
    mb_language('uni');
    mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

$getquery=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM activitytest1");
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($getquery)) 
{
$type=$rows['type'];
$description=$rows['description'];
$author=$rows['author'];
$pre=$rows['pre'];
$while=$rows['while'];
$postact=$rows['postact'];
$outcome=$rows['outcome'];
$path=$rows['path'];
$books=$rows['books'];
$grouping=$rows['grouping'];
$time=$rows['time'];

echo '<br/>

<table width="909" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="125">' . $type . '</th>
    <td width="680">' . $description . '</th>
    <td width="120">' . $author . '</th>
  </tr></table> <br/>' .  $pre . '<br/>' . $while. '<br/>' . $postact . '<br/>' . $outcome . '<br/>' . $path . '<br/>' . $books . '<br/>' . $grouping . '<br/>' . $time . '
   <hr size="1"/> ' ;}

?>     
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test 1</title>
</head>
<body>

<br>
<table width="909" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <th width="125" scope="col">Type</th>
    <th width="680" scope="col">Description</th>
    <th width="120" scope="col">Author</th>
  </tr></table>
  <br>
<form action="index.php" method="POST">

<table width="909" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
     <td width="125"><label>

     </label>
       <select name="type" id="type" onChange="display(this,'Task','Semi-task','Practice','Exercise','Lead-in');">
         <option value="Unselected" selected="selected">Choose one:</option>
         <option value="Task">Task</option>
         <option value="Semi-task">Semi-task</option>
         <option value="Practice">Practice</option>
         <option value="Exercise">Exercise</option>
         <option value="Lead-in">Lead-in</option>
         <option value="Game">Game</option>
         <option value="Video">Video</option>
         <option value="Song">Song</option>
         <option value="Mimio">Mimio</option>
         <option value="Other">Other</option>
       </select></td>
    <td width="680"><div id="Semi-task" style="display: none;">
      Pre:<br>
    </div>
        <div id="Exercise"  style="display: none;">While:</div>
        <br>
        <div id="Practice" style="display: none;">
      Post:<br>
      <br>
       </div>
        <div id="Task"  style="display: none;"> Outcome: <br />
        <textarea name="description" cols="70" rows="2"></textarea>
            <br />
        </div>
        <div id="Lead-in" style="display: none;">
      Link/Path:<br>
      <br>
       </div></td>
    <td width="120"><input name="author" type="text" size="12" maxlength="25" /></td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
       <td colspan="3">      <textarea name="pre" id="Pre" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
                       <br /><textarea name="while" id="While" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
                       <br /><textarea name="postact" id="Post" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
                       <br /><textarea name="outcome" id="Outcome" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
                       <br /><input type="text" name="path" id="Path" />
                       <br /><input type="text" name="books" id="Books" />
                       <br /><input type="text" name="grouping" id="Grouping" />
                       <br /><input type="text" name="time" id="Time" />
                       </td>
     </tr>
    <tr>
       <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Comment" /></td>
     </tr>
</table>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Please be nice, guys, I am a total newbie at this. :)

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_*` as it is depreciated.  Instead you should be using `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra comma at the end of the mySQL code.

Try this: `$insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO activitytest1 (type, description, author, pre, while, postact, outcome, path, books, grouping, time) VALUES ('".$_POST['type']."','".$_POST['description']."','".$_POST['author']."','".$_POST['pre']."', '".$_POST['while']."','".$_POST['postact']."','".$_POST['outcome']."','".$_POST['path']."', '".$_POST['books']."','".$_POST['grouping']."','".$_POST['time']."')");`

Comment: Thanks , Asfer. But the problem isnt the display:none thing. Actually I adapted this code from a perfectly working table (that only had three fields/variables. I really don't understand why this code doesn't work when if I take off the new variables and keep only the three original ones it works perfectly again. I am REALLY new to this... so, can you please explain what you meant by "First check the data you are passing is valid. Your $_POST['description'] field is empty so pointer is not coming inside mysql_query() function.", and maybe even be so kind as to give an example?

Comment: Wrong comment for the wrong answer... are you sure mine did not work?

Comment: Yeah, aviation978. it still doesn't work after I took off the extra comma. Thank you for your feedback, though!

Comment: I have adapted the code to become mysqli and now it's working (it sends the data to the database). But now I'm getting the "Notice: undefined index" as soon as I open the page and it creates a null line. If I fill in the fields and submit it will work and they will be saved in the database alright, though. I think I need a code that will tell "submit" not to send data to the database it empty. What code is that?

Answer (score 0):

First check the data you are passing is valid. Your $_POST['description'] field is empty so pointer is not coming inside mysql_query() function.

Another think i saw in your code you have display : none; a div which has $_POST['description'] element. Remove that display : none OR remove the validation part for that element.